# How do I get current network location name?

Tags: cocoa, networking, macos, system-configuration

In system network preference there are some location names.How to get the current or active network location name and list of all network locations? 
I guess SystemConfiguration.framework supports this but i didn't get exactly which API to use.
Thanks in advance for your answer. 
Regards
Devara Gudda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`SCPreferencesCreate`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Networking/Reference/SCPreferences/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCPreferencesCreate) to get the preferences, then [`SCNetworkSetCopyAll`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkSetCopyAll) to get just the network locations. [`SCNetworkSetGetName`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkSetGetName) will get the name of a location.

```
SCPreferencesRef prefs = SCPreferencesCreate(NULL, @"SystemConfiguration", NULL);
NSArray *locations = (NSArray *)SCNetworkSetCopyAll(prefs);
for (id item in locations) {
    NSString *name = (NSString *)SCNetworkSetGetName((SCNetworkSetRef)item);
    ...
}
CFRelease(locations);
CFRelease(prefs);
```

Read "[System Configuration Programming Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_Intro/SC_Intro.html)" for more.

Comment: Thanks it's working.
I am using SCNetworkSetCopyCurrent to get the current n/w location.

Answer (score 1):

This is a swift 5.1 implementation to get list of all available network location

```
    func getAvailabeNetworkLocation() -> [String]
{
    var results = [String]()

    
    var prefs : SCPreferences
    prefs = SCPreferencesCreate (nil, "Softech" as CFString, nil)!
    var sets : CFArray
    sets = SCNetworkSetCopyAll (prefs)!
    
    let count = CFArrayGetCount(sets) as Int
    var newSet : SCNetworkSet? = nil
    var bFound : Bool = false
    
   

    
    for nIndex  in 0..<count {
     let mySet = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (sets, nIndex)
     let key = Unmanaged<SCNetworkSet>.fromOpaque(mySet!)
        newSet = key.takeUnretainedValue()
        let name : String = SCNetworkSetGetName(newSet!)! as String
        print("Network location name: \(name)")
     results.append(name)
    }
    return results
}
```